# Save images to NSLibraryDirectory in a particular folder

Tags: iphone, directory

I want to save the images in NSLibraryDirectory, the code i am using is replacing image, when next image is saved.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory,        NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"images.doc"];
UIImage *image = [arrayImages objectAtIndex:0];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];
```

Comment: Of course it replaces, since you specify a constant filename... what else would you expect?

Comment: I thing your mistake is you'r wring image.doc. put image.png

Comment: if we change it to png, then also it is replacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Each time you have to use a different name** that isn't already used.So You have  to change the file name Each time.

If you want work it **even after app restarted** ,Save the index value to **NSUserDefaults**

**.h file**

```
int index;
```

Change your code as in .m

```
index = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HighScore"];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NewFolder"];
NSString *dynamicimagename = [[@"/images" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HighScore"]] stringByAppendingFormat:@".doc"];
NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:dynamicimagename];
UIImage *image = [arrayImages objectAtIndex:0];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
BOOL isWritten = [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];

index++;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:index forKey:@"HighScore"];
```

Comment: It is but when the app is restarted it does not continue further addition but it starts replacing again.

Comment: when the app is restarted ,index value will agin comes as zero. So it will replace older images

Comment: exactly its not the solution then

Comment: Please tell how can we save into a specific folder in document directory, not in document directory.

Comment: change the path as NSString *dynamicimagename = [[@"yourSubFolder/images" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HighScore"]] stringByAppendingFormat:@".doc"];

Comment: give the path as NSString *documentsDirectory = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"New Folder"];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18846/discussion-between-ramshad-and-apple-datasource)

Answer (score 3):

```
 NSMutableArray *imag = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1333681269.jpeg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"image001-794043.jpeg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Circle.png"], nil];

 for(int i=0;i<[imag count];i++)
 {
       NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
       NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
       NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"savedImage%i.png",i];
       NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
       NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([imag objectAtIndex:i]);
       [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];
}
```

Comment: giving warning: Incompatible pointer types passing 'NSString *' to parameter of type 'UIImage *'

Comment: Now check this is what you were going wrong UIImage *image = [arrayImages objectAtIndex:0]; always objectAtIndex:0 takes the same image rite ? i had changed it i.. now please check and let me know

Comment: No bro its not, please check it yourself before posting.

Comment: and change where you increment it kills the app.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18790/discussion-between-venkat-manohar-and-randeep)